# My Eclipse with Spring Boot has been running "Spring Boot Validations Builder" on one project for hours now

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, spring-tools-4

I'm using Eclipse 2023-06 on Windows 11.

I have the Spring Boot plugin set installed, with v4.19.1, the latest available at this time.

In the last few days, I've been severely hampered with either the "Spring Boot Language Server" or the "Spring Boot Validations Builder", simply running forever.  When the SBLS job appears to be hung, I've just had to kill the external javaw process associated with that. That sometimes helps, but sometimes it just starts it up again and hangs again.

About 2 hours ago I decided to simply reboot and start everything again, and I then left for lunch.  I started Eclipse, and it started a bunch of jobs, including the "Spring Boot Validations Builder", for one particular project.  I came back an hour later, and it had barely changed.

I then tried cancelling that job, which in my experience is typically a waste of time, as it seems to never respect that.  It's been running in that state for about 20 minutes now.

I've tried to turn off settings in the Spring section of preferences, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

If it helps, here is a screenshot of my Progress View, which hasn't changed at all in hours now.

[image]

Comment: And to address @xpetersue 's comment in a deleted answer, I have no issue with memory. My laptop has 32g ram, my Eclipse process has maxmem of 3g. I was seeing some errors connecting to SO, but otherwise I see no network issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the GitHub issue that you filed for this: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1103

I added a comment with a few assumptions why this might happen. The workaround for this is to disable the `Reconciling of Java Sources` in the `Preferences -> Spring -> Open Rewrite`.

The real underlying solution will ship with the next release of the Spring Tools (4.20.0), expected to arrive mid to late September 2023.

Comment: Actually, the underlying issue might be something different from what I thought it is, so we need to analyze this in more depth. The solution I was referring to is related to slow validation performance inside of the language server, but this seems to be a different issue, so please follow-up in the GitHub issue for more advice and details.